# Reverse engineering this very common component tester

Tags: reverse-engineering, test-equipment, hacking

I'm talking about this common variety of component testers [here](https://img.banggood.com/file/products/20170206003730GM328A-User-Manual.pdf).

Here's my goal: To extend it so it can properly identify MOSFETs & IGBTs even if the threshold voltage is higher than 5V.

I was hoping most of its implementation involved multiplexing to different subcircuits, each testing if the component matched the type, even though the parts count were surprisingly low. How wrong I was.

It looks like somebody already has reverse engineered this tester:

[image]

Looking at the schematic he has probed, it really seems nearly all was on chip. The ADC is component is on chip and everything else was done via software.

I haven't given up yet (or rather we shouldn't.)

Is it possible for a hypothetical MOSFET/IGBT, the test par, to be driven in the linear region by the firmware, where the gate is fed with a signal from a positive or a negative rail (depending on the determined PN-type,) that is supplied externally with other plugs rather than from pins of the microcontroller? I'm willing to add much larger voltage rails here.

I mean, a lot of things are possible, but would this still be sane?

---

EDIT:
I proposed a negative voltage, so, with the p-type, the gate can swing even lower, with minimal modification to the firmware.

When it's gotten to work, then we simply add the magnitudes of negative & positive & put that as positive rail & get the firmware to have source/emitter connect to it. Then gate can be pulled closer & closer as needed to 0V.

Comment: It's an open source design: https://www.mikrocontroller.net/articles/AVR_Transistortester

Comment: I know it's open-sourced, but I think https://github.com/robsoncouto summarized the schematic better. Though he kinda made it sound that the schematic was unavailable from the original project site.